# How to filter by Optional types in scala spark dataSets

Tags: scala, apache-spark

The code below I get a value from kafka as an array of bytes. ToJobEvent converts those bytes into Option[JobEvent], then I want to filter the Nones out of the JobEvent then finally extract the JobEvent out of the Maybe monad. What is the proper way to do this in scala spark?

```
val jobEventDS = kafkaDS
      .select($"value".as[Array[Byte]])
      .map(binaryData => FromThrift.ToJobEvent(binaryData))
      .filter(MaybeJobEvent => MaybeJobEvent match {
        case Some(_) => true
        case None => false
      }).map {
      case Some(jobEvent) => jobEvent
      case None => null
    }
```

The above code doesn't work. Just an example I want to get working.

Comment: Maybe instead of `filter + map` you may `.collect { case Some(jobEvent) => jobEvent }`.

Comment: I am not sure if this will work in Spark, but in regular Scala, you can just call flatten after .map(binaryData => FromThrift.ToJobEvent(binaryData)) and it will unwrap Some and discard None.

Comment: So if I'm right, that should be .map(binaryData => FromThrift.ToJobEvent(binaryData)).flatten

Comment: Try using flatmap instead of map so that you can emit 0 records in cases where you do not create JobEvent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first option is to use `flatMap`

```
df.select($"value".as[Array[Byte]])
      .flatMap(binaryData => FromThrift.ToJobEvent(binaryData) match {
          case Some(value) => Seq(value)
          case None => Seq()
        }
      })
```

The second is to use `Tuple1` as a holder

```
df.select($"value".as[Array[Byte]])
      .map(binaryData => {
        BinaryHolder(binaryData).toCaseClassMonad() match {
          case Some(value) => Tuple1(value)
          case None => Tuple1(null)
        }
      })
      .filter(tuple => tuple._1 != null)
      .map(tuple => tuple._1)
```

A bit of explanation.

If yous `MaybeJobEvent` is a case class or instance of `Product`, Spark won't be able to handle it.
See [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-2.4/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/encoders/ExpressionEncoder.scala#L53).

> Cannot create encoder for Option of Product type, because Product type is represented as a row, and the entire row can not be null in Spark SQL like normal databases. You can wrap your type with Tuple1 if you do want top level null Product objects, e.g. instead of creating `Dataset[Option[MyClass]]`, you can do something like `val ds: Dataset[Tuple1[MyClass]] = Seq(Tuple1(MyClass(...)), Tuple1(null)).toDS`

Some examples:

```
case class BinaryHolder(value: Array[Byte]) {
  def toStrMonad(): Option[String] = new String(value) match {
    case "abc" => None
    case _ => Some(new String(value))
  }

  def toCaseClassMonad(): Option[MyString] = new String(value) match {
    case "abc" => None
    case _ => Some(MyString(new String(value)))
  }
}

//case classe is also Product 
case class MyString(str: String)
```

Creating Dataset:

```
val ds = List(
      BinaryHolder("abc".getBytes()),
      BinaryHolder("dbe".getBytes()),
      BinaryHolder("aws".getBytes()),
      BinaryHolder("qwe".getBytes())
    ).toDS()
```

This works fine:

```
val df: DataFrame = ds.toDF()
    df.select($"value".as[Array[Byte]])
      .map(binaryData => {
        BinaryHolder(binaryData).toStrMonad()
      })
      .show()

+-----+
|value|
+-----+
| null|
|  dbe|
|  aws|
|  qwe|
+-----+
```

But this **fails** with the exception

```
df.select($"value".as[Array[Byte]])
      .map(binaryData => {
        //Option[MyString]
        BinaryHolder(binaryData).toCaseClassMonad()
      })
      .show()

UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot create encoder for Option of Product type...
```

Returning nulls for a typed dataset also won't work

```
 df.select($"value".as[Array[Byte]])
      .map(binaryData => {
        BinaryHolder(binaryData).toCaseClassMonad() match {
          case Some(value) => value
          case None => null
        }
      })
```

throws

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Null value appeared in non-nullable field:
top level Product input object
If the schema is inferred from a Scala tuple/case class, or a Java bean, please try to use scala.Option[_] or other nullable types (e.g. java.lang.Integer instead of int/scala.Int).
```